# Prove that one can choose $400$ of these green integers whose total sum is equal to $200,000$

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Let $S=\{1, 2, 3, ..., 1000\}$. Bob has decided to paint $701$ of these integers in green. Prove that one can choose $400$ of these green integers whose total sum is equal to $200,000$

I know this has to do with the pigeonhole principle but I am having trouble setting it up. Here what I have so far:

We can denote the set that consists of two elements: $k$ and $1000-k$ by $A_k$.
This means $A_k=\{k, 1000-k\}$ (let's call this a set) for $k=1, 2, 3, ..., 500$.
Now Bob will paint $701$ of these numbers in green, this means since we have $500$ sets, there will be $201$ sets where both numbers of the set are painted in green.

Now I do not know why we can always choose $400$ green numbers that sum to $200,000$?

Comment: Well, all you need is $200$ such pairs....(note:  that's all you have, actually.  the pair $\{500,500\}$ doesn't count.)

Comment: @lulu can you explain why we only need $200$ pairs? That's the part that I do not understand.

Comment: Each pair adds to $1000$, the sum of all the pairs is $200,000$

Comment: I note that you define $A_k$ in two different ways.  I'm using $\{k,1000-k\}$.

Comment: I fixed it, I made a mistake.

Comment: Yes, but I preferred the "mistake".  That is, I like the pairs that add to $1,000$.  You have $499$ of them, with the number $500$ left over.  If only $199$ of these were all Green then the number of green numbers would be at most $2\times 199+300+1=699$, no good!  So you must have at least $200$ Green pairs of the form $\{k,1000-k\}$.

Comment: I see, if we say $A_k=\{k, 1000-k\}$ for $k=1, 2, ..., 499$ then we will have $499$ sets that sum to $1000$ and the last set would be $\{500, 1000\}$, so after $701$ numbers are painted in green, at least $200$ of the sets that sum to $1000$ will have both elements painted in green which is exactly how much we need. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, you correctly point out that I forgot the number $1,000$.  Doesn't change much.  Now we have two unpaired numbers $500$ and $1000$ but if we had only $199$ Green pairs then we'd get at most $2\times 199+300+2=700$ which is still one short, so the argument still holds.

Comment: Actually I think $700$ green numbers would be sufficient, because if you have only $199$ of the $\{k,1000-k\}$ pairs painted green, you must also have painted the numbers $500$ and $1000$--and you can use the green $1000$ to bring the sum to $200,000$.

Comment: @DavidK  But then you would only have $2\times 199+1$ terms in your sum....and the OP wanted exactly $400$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let we define a green number $k$ as *good* if $1000-k$ is also a green number. We just have to show that there are at least $400$ (i.e. $200$ pairs of)  *good* green numbers. Let we consider the couples $\{1,999\},\{2,998\},\ldots,\{499,501\}$. We have to paint in green at least $700$ of their elements: if we assume$^{\color{purple}{(T)}}$ that there are at most $199$ pairs of good green numbers, there are at most $199$ couples completely colored in green, so there are at least $499-199=300$ couples with just $0$ or $1$ element painted in green. So there are at most $300+2\cdot 199=698$ green-colored integers in $[1,1000]$, but our hypothesis gives us that they are $701$, so $\color{purple}{(T)}$ cannot hold.